# What's the difference between fans of a Facebook page and followers of a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, followers

Some time ago Facebook introduced followers for a Facebook page. So now Facebook pages can have both followers and fans. They have separated statistics and everything. In one of my page, followers and fans grow and different rates. 
My question is,  What's the difference between fans of a Facebook page and followers of a Facebook page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Liking a Business Page**
When an individual likes your page on Facebook, they automatically opt into following your page. This means that your posts will be seen in their feed and you will be listed in their ‘liked’ directory. It’s important to know that users can unfollow your page after liking your page, which means won’t see your content very often.

**Following a Business Page**
Facebook users have the option to follow a page without hitting the like button. These types of followers will still see your posts in their newsfeed, but they won’t be considered a like on your page. This option was set up for people who didn’t want to befriend someone on Facebook but still wanted to see their posts

Answer (score 1):

The differences can be confusing, especially with Facebook's terminology. Basically, the difference is this: *liking* a page shows your endorsement of it, and others can see that you like it, whereas *following* a page keeps you informed about new posts made on or by that page.

When you choose to follow a page, you'll be notified of posts to that page (though you can change the level of notifications) similarly to how you are notified when your friends post. Liking a page just shows others that you like that business, organization, group, etc.

One interesting thing to note is that when you like a page, Facebook will automatically add you as a follower of that page as well (though you can easily stop following the page if you want).

[BRSM.io](https://brsm.io/facebook-likes-versus-followers/) goes more in-depth with the differences:

> When people sign up to ‘follow’ your business on Facebook, this means that they wish to be notified of your business’ progress. Perhaps you own a retail shop and use Facebook as a way of posting pictures of exciting new products. All of your followers will be notified, in their news feeds, of these new trends. Alternatively, you might like to post daily statuses that will draw attention to in-store promotions. Your Facebook followers will similarly be notified of these incredible business deals.
>
> To form a contrast, being ‘liked’ on Facebook does not establish such a wide-reaching relationship. If someone enjoyed their business experience with you, they may choose to ‘like’ your Facebook page. Doing so is a way of promoting a business they like, without having to follow all of that business’ marketing ventures on a daily basis.

Comment: Voted up for the research, but it still  not clear. Since we are talking about a Facebook page, neither fans nor followers of a page can be a relationship between 2 profiles, so it sounds like it says nothing relevant?

Comment: I dont think that article is explaining the difference between Facebook page fans and Facebook page followers, I think it's explaining the difference between Facebook page fans and Facebook profile followers. But not long ago Facebook enabled followers also for Facebook pages, who it seems to me, they are out of that explanation

Comment: @Pablo Thanks for the response. I've updated my answer with a more accurate distinction between the two.